# Are there any decent vocal time / date / appointment announcers for Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, clock, reminder, alarm

I'm looking for a Fedora / Linux application which announces the system time vocally at regular intervals, similar to the time announcement feature Mac OSX has. A quick look around Google hasn't revealed much.

Evolution calendar appointment integration, GNOME integration and other helpful organisational features are highly desirable, but not essential. The application should automatically announce time vocally, at a bare minimum, however.

Cheers for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

ESpeak doesn't give you what you need ??
I used it few years ago to announce alarmes for specific systems on a hypervision room ...
It was very helpfull. You can customize the accent, the voice and other stuffs.

[ESpeak Project](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Seems to be just a speech synthesis engine library and executable. Do any time and calendar announcing plugins exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit Google translate, even in you own language.

```
google-say -ru 16:43
google-say "Splendid supa-ninja, let's do it\!"
google-say -ru "Супер юзер дот ком"
man bash | grep -m1 GNU | google-say
```

---

```
!#/bin/bash
google-say-ru () { google-say-generic -ru $@; }
google-say () { google-say-generic $@; } 
google-say-generic () {
    local WORDS service _lang;
    if [ "$1" == "-ru" ]; then
        shift;
        _lang=ru;
    else
        _lang=en;
    fi;
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        cat "$1" | while read l; do
            google-say-generic "-${_lang}" "$l";
        done;
        return 0;
    else
        if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
            WORDS="`cat | tr ' ' +`";
        else
            WORDS="`echo $@ |tr ' ' +`";
        fi;
    fi;
    echo $WORDS | tr '+' ' ';
    service="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=${_lang}&q=$WORDS";
    wget -q -U Mozilla -O- "$service" | mpg321 --quiet -
}
```

Another option is [Festival Speech Synthesis System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_Speech_Synthesis_System)

Comment: These suggestions consist of only speech synthesis libraries and executables. It seems I'd still have to write code to interface them with gnome-clock and/or Evolution calendar libs to get the kind of functionality I need. Again, I need a (preferably already written) applet which feeds appointment and time information from GNOME clock and / or Evolution calendar output streams into a speech synthesis lib which, in turn, vocally announces time and appointments at regular intervals.

Comment: I kinda figured. Sorry if the answer is not useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

on this link [setting-up-a-talking-clock-easily-in-linux](http://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/setting-up-a-talking-clock-easily-in-linux/) are some examples to do this.